# Modify browser request to Load different file while visiting specific URL only

Tags: url, browser

I couldnt find similar topic (maybe exists)...

Whenever my browser try to load

`example.com/abc.js`, instead I want to load this file actually:

`mysite.com/abc.js`

(p.s. I DONT OWN THOSE SITES, I WANT ONLY TO TRICK MY BROWSER TO LOAD DIFFERENTLY **ONLY  ONE** SPECIFIC FILE.)

Comment: you can use .htaccess to redirect

Comment: I dont own that site at all

Answer (score 0):

with htaccess redirect

```
Redirect http://come_from/abc.js http://send_to.com/abc.js
```

Comment: I dont need your answer, be as far from me as you can, with your current avatar.

Comment: i really don't care what you think of a picture, that has nothing to do with providing an answer to the question posed...  which was correct...   don't you think this caveat "(p.s. I DONT OWN THOSE SITES, I WANT ONLY TO TRICK MY BROWSER TO LOAD DIFFERENTLY ONLY ONE SPECIFIC FILE.)" would have been useful information to have in the first place?       best i can come up with here...  is your question is a duplicate of many under browser extension redirects and that you're an idiot and likely up to malicious purpose with the kind of crap you're asking....